# Why doesn't my Collections.binarySearch work?

Tags: java, collections

```
public class AppTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Human> humans = new ArrayList<Human>();
        humans.add(new Human("A", 25));
        humans.add(new Human("B", 24));
        humans.add(new Human("C", 24));

        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(humans, new Human("A", 25)));
        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(humans, new Human("B", 24)));
        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(humans, new Human("C", 24)));
    }
}

class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Human(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int compareTo(Human arg0) {
        return name.compareTo(arg0.name);
    }

}
```

The output is below:

```
0
1
-2
```

May I know why the output is not 0 1 2 instead of 0 1 -2 ? Is there something wrong with my code or my understanding?

Thanks

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: As with many if not most questions of this form, the occult question you are really asking is "why doesn't my code work?" The answer is that the collection you are searching isn't sorted, contrary to the requirement clearly stated in the Javadoc:['The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(List) method) prior to making this call.'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T))

Comment: First you need to know that binary search always works on sorted data. Your List is not sorted, and binarySearch method could not find your instance in your list(Its assuming that list is sorted and break the list search area). If any value could not find in list, method returns negative value(-(low+1). Low is search start index.

So basically if you want this example working as expected you need to write "Collections.sort(humans);" after creating your list and before starting search.

Answer (score 1):

This method returns the index of the value to be searched, if found in the    ArrayList.Otherwise it `returns (- (X) - 1)` where `X` is the index where the the search value would be inserted.
          (i.e.) index of first element that is grater than the search value
          or ArrayList.size(), if all elements of an ArrayList are less
          than the search value.